# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument / Installation Script

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, remote-desktop

I am a student and am very new to PowerShell.

I am trying to get my `msi` to download remotely but i keep encountering an error.

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '\\share\folder\Path to msi'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
    + PSComputerName        : RemoteDesktopName
```

Here is my script:

```
$msi = @(\\share\folder\Path to msi)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName PCname -ScriptBlock {param($msi) Start-Process msiexec.exe /i "\\Path to msi" /qn /passive -Wait 
 Start-Sleep 5 } -ArgumentList $msi
```

Could anyone please help me? Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to make `$msi` an array if the only thing you parse is a string of the Path. Also, why would you use `"\Path to msi"` inside the `Invoke-Command` if you parse `$msi`?

Edit: You should probaly parse the arguments to the `msiexec.exe` via `-Argumentlist`.

Try this:

```
$msi = "Path to msi"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName PCname -ScriptBlock {param($msi) Start-Process msiexec.exe -Wait -ArgumentList "/I $msi /qn /passive"} -ArgumentList $msi
```

Comment: Error still persists after i made the changes unfortunately.

Comment: @LeeHanyee I edited my answer, you have to use `"` instead of `'` in the Argumentlist. Please try again, it works on my system.

Comment: Error is gone now, but my msi is still not installing on the other server. But that could be due to the server permissions will have to check. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @LeeHanyee No Problem. If the answer helped you, please mark it as correct. :)